# How to make javascript interact with something in a different element (html)?

Tags: javascript, html, html-helper

I am trying to make a webpage with a form where you have an input box and a slider. The slider should display the value of the slider but it only works if put it directly in to the main class but not if I put it in anything else for example the form.

So it works if I put the slider part in main class like this.

```
<div class="main">
        <!-- slider -->
        <div class="box">
            <input step="0.1" type="range" min="0.1" max="5" value="1" name="amount">
        </div>
        <!-- value display -->
        <div class="value">1</div>
            <div class="field">
                <h1>Halao</h1><br><br>
                <form action="https://formsubmit.co/your@email.com" method="POST">
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required><br><br>
                    
                    <br>
                    <button type="submit">Send</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    <script>
        const slider = document.querySelector("input");
        const value = document.querySelector(".value");
        value.textContent = slider.value
        slider.oninput = function(){
            value.textContent = this.value;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

But if it put in the form the value display does not show.

```
<div class="main">
            <div class="field">
                <h1>Halao</h1><br><br>
                <form action="https://formsubmit.co/your@email.com" method="POST">
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required><br><br>
                    <!-- slider -->
                    <div class="box">
                        <input step="0.1" type="range" min="0.1" max="5" value="1" name="amount">
                    </div>
                    <!-- value display -->
                    <div class="value">1</div>
                    <br>
                    <button type="submit">Send</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    <script>
        const slider = document.querySelector("input");
        const value = document.querySelector(".value");
        value.textContent = slider.value
        slider.oninput = function(){
            value.textContent = this.value;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

I would really appreciate it if some one could explain why it is not working and help me to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

In the form, you have a

```html
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
```

which gets selected as `querySelector('input')`

Either use `querySelector('input[type="range"]')`, add it id, or a class